# How to fix SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using babel plugins,

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
npm install --save-dev babel-register
```

but displayed this error:

> **SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'**

Could you please check this issue?

```
F:\react\test\live\testserver\node_modules\reactjs-popup\dist\index.css:1
.popup-content{margin:auto;background:#fff;width:50%;padding:5px;border:1px solid #d7d7d7}[role=tooltip].popup-content{width:200px;box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.16);border-radius:5px}.popup-overlay{background:rgba(0,0,0,.5)}[data-popup=tooltip].popup-overlay{background:transparent}.popup-arrow{-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0 -3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.16));filter:drop-shadow(0 -3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.16));color:#fff;stroke-width:2px;stroke:#d7d7d7;stroke-dasharray:30px;stroke-dashoffset:-54px;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0}
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (F:\react\test\live\testserver\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:/react/test/live/testserver/src/StoreComponent/OfferList.jsx:6:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
PS F:\react\test\live\testserver>
```

webpack config file:

```
require("babel-register")({
    presets: ["es2015", "react"]
  });
  
  const router = require('./Routes').default;
  const Sitemap = require('react-router-sitemap').default;
  
  (
      new Sitemap(router)
          .build('https://mi-awesome-website.com')
          .save('./public/sitemap.xml')
  );
```

Comment: Can you show me you webpack config?

Comment: I added webpack config above.

Comment: It doesnt looks like webpack config, it should starts with "module.exports = ..."

Comment: could you please provide correct webpack config file please

Answer (score 0):

Try with this config to load css properly

```
require.extensions['.scss'] = () => {
  return;
};
require.extensions['.css'] = () => {
  return;
};
```

or can use with ur existed config:

```
require('babel-register')({
  presets: ["es2015", "react"],
  ignore: /\.styl$/,
});
```

For Sitemap with custom routes -

> router.js

```
import React from 'react';
//Switch was introduced in react router v4
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import PageOne from "./pages/page-1";
import PageTwo from "./pages/page-2";
import PageThree from "./pages/page-3";
import App from "./App";

function Routes() {
  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Switch> 
  <Route exact path='/' component={App}/>
  <Route exact path='/page-1' component={PageOne}/>
  <Route exact path='/page-2' component={PageTwo}/>
  <Route exact path='/page-3' component={PageThree}/>
  </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

export default Routes;

Then replace your

```
const router = require('./Routes').default;
```

by

```
const router = require('./routes').default;
or
const router = require('./routes.js').default;
```

Comment: if i run showing this error: return new Sitemap(router()).build("http://localhost:3000/");TypeError: router is not a function

Comment: Shall i call js this format: require.extensions['.js'] = () => {
  return;
};

Comment: If do that, then your .js files will be ignored. Make sure that browser can support (can compile) files that means in es5.